# Get filename and path where curl -o saved the output

Tags: bash, pipe, curl, chmod

I'm trying to create a new command by downloading a gist from Github. I need to add an `+x` permission to the downloaded file. I can do it like this.

```
sudo curl -s $URL -o /usr/bin/hello && sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/hello
```

---

Although I want to grab `-o` value and add an `+x` permission to it. I imagine it as something like:

```
sudo curl -s $URL -o /usr/bin/hello | ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  chmod +x this_after_o_value
```

Is there a way I can achieve it? Awk, sed, tr, cut? I'm looking for a fairly simple solution.

Comment: It is not possible like you imagine, as `curl` doesn't report where it saved the file (not even with `-v`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a variable for this task.

```
output="/usr/bin/hello"
sudo curl -s $URL -o $output && sudo chmod +x $output
```

Comment: Yes. This solution is satisfactory!